# CSS3 :empty not working

Tags: html, css

I have a Wordpress Website and in a Theme I load some Data: if the div.description is empty, the height of description should be 0.
But it's not working. Here is the Code how it's shown in the Browser: maybe 
 is not considered as empty? (PS: Using SASS

```css
.one-project {
  .description {
    height: 0;
}

&:hover {
  .description {
    height: 50px;
   }
 .description:empty {
    height: 0px;
  }
}

This is the output in the Browser:
```

```html
<div class="one-project">
  <div class="details">
    <div class="title">My Title</div>
      <div class="description"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is how it is in my Template (Wordpress)

```
<div class="description">
<?php
 $shortexcerpt = get_field( 'excerpt' );
echo ($shortexcerpt ? $shortexcerpt: '');
?>
 </div>
```

Comment: This HTML `<div class="description"/>` is wrong open and close the div tag fully. i.e.  `<div class="description"></div>`

Comment: why u r using  self closing div `<div class="description"/>`....??

Comment: I just updated the example, since the html code is the browser's output. In the Template there is a closing tag </div>

Comment: Why not just checking if the value is not empty, and then output the element to the DOM? Something like `<?php $shortexcerpt = get_field( 'excerpt' ); if( !empty($shortexcerpt) ) {?><div class="description"><?php echo htmlentities($shortexcerpt); ?></div><?php } ?>` Doing this will allow you to just set a default style that is not depended on the content of the element

Comment: So there are now styles allowed for the div to be completely empty? I have no padding, but I have margin, display, line-height, font-size, opacity.

Comment: I did what Alon said, it still print's out /> not </div> even thought it should... but: :empty works now! Strange!

Comment: So it works now, which is good! But there must be something else that you're missing out as it definitely should not make a div a self-closing  element. Perhaps you're outputting some  HTML from your DB? Because the code that you posted in the question should work

Comment: So, the Problem was, that i had a break in my code. I put everything in one line. The div and the php - not it works!
AND I just looked in the firebug - not in the sourcecode - in the sourcecode it is </div> :)

Comment: @Paulie_D: Padding is a layout/CSS thing, not a content/HTML thing, and doesn't affect whether an element matches :empty. This has less to do with :empty and more to do with />.

Comment: @parvaneh Off topic, but what version of Firefox are you using? Firebug no longer works in the latest one. _View Selection Source_ and _Inspect Element_ both say `<div></div>` though.